# Weird php showing

Tags: php, html, implementation

I am doing a website. That website is for learning and it has some login form.

I did the website, and the login and much more, but there is a weird problem.I created page called: **user.php**, on that page I pasted code from my index page(that code is perfect and runs very well), and implemented some php...

Now the problem: The site itself, without any PHP works great, However, if I do whatever PHP, like just `<?php echo "Some Error Message";?>` The site is not working, I can't overwrite it on server and when I open it, its just a code, not a website.

For sure, there is link to my sign in page: http://david.addagio.cz/registrace.php  ... Use **david** as an username, and **david123** as an password. You should now have open nice website, that works great, but if i try to do ANY PHP on it, the site disappear and it is just code again.

Comment: You miss semicolon in <?php echo "Some Error Message"?>. So Have you checked it with proper syntex?

Comment: Yep, that i missed, but the problem still is there, it is not in this, I tried just <?php?> and it was not working

Comment: You need to look at your log file

Comment: which php version you are using??

Comment: May seems funny, but it is possible that your hosting plan is without php?
Just simple .html pages?

Comment: this is a hosting issue, you should talk to your hosting's support

Comment: Yeah, it was because of no more space on server... thanks for support :)